# What makes particles stable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Quantum Field Theory says that particles are merely a disturbance in a field.  Virtual particles can pop in and out of existance.  I am made of particles.  The particles that make me must be stable.  What makes particles stable versus temporary virtual particles and quantum tunneling particles?

Comment: "*Quantum Field Theory says that particles are merely a disturbance in a field. Virtual particles can pop in and out of existance.*" No and no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: virtual particles are a side-effect of the mathematical formalism of quantum field theory; they can be used to understand observable real particles, which aren't going anywhere.

"Real" particles satisfy an on-shell energy-momentum relation such as $p^\mu p_\mu =m^2$ if we work in units with $c=1$. If you also set $\hbar=1$, we can alternatively describe this as a dispersion relation in terms of the four-frequency $k^\mu:=\hbar^{-1}p^\mu$, viz. $k^\mu k_\mu = m^2$. In field terms, such results follow from the field's Euler-Lagrange equation, which is why they're on-shell results.

"Virtual" particles, which have the short-lived existence you describe, are "off-shell" i.e. don't obey this energy-momentum relation. Mathematically, they're discovered by writing the action $S$ in terms of a source current $J$. The path integral formalism replaces the classical stationary action principle with probability amplitudes proportional to $e^{iS}$. If we Fourier-transform to work in terms of four-frequencies, virtual particles contribute to the physics in inverse proportion to the extent of the energy-momentum relation violation. For example, for a scalar field $\phi$ we have the functional integral $$\int \mathcal{D}\phi e^{iS}\propto e^{iW},\,W:=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{J(-k) J(k)}{k^2-m^2}.$$

Particle accelerators can transfer four-momentum so as to bring an off-shell particle on-shell, allowing us to detect previously undetectable virtual particles that are now real.

Comment: plus in answer to the  general title,  quantum numbers conservation.

Comment: @annav In fact, such conservation laws play an important role in more complicated examples than that of the scalar field. For example, the $J^2$ term for a vector is $-J^\mu (g_{\mu\nu}-m^{-2}k_\mu k_\nu)J^\nu$, which looks like it will diverge at $m=0$ (which would be a shame, since that's how we impose certain symmetries). Luckily, $k\cdot j$ gets rid of the $m^{-2}$ term.

Comment: Ok.  Umm.  I think I need a book or something.  I understand integral.  I know h bar, c, e, imaginary numbers, momentum, scalars but no idea on S, D, momentum p with superscript/subscript u etc.  Suggestions?

Comment: @AmethystAmulet $S$ is the action described in any text on Lagrangian mechanics. In quantum field theory we sometimes have "functional integrals", where the variable you integrate over is itself a function; that's what the $\mathcal{D}$ denotes. A QFT textbook will explain the functional calculus you need for this. The $\mu$ (mu, not u) super/subscript is a relativistic index, so any relativity textbook will explain it. (In fact, you should read up on relativity before QFT, since the latter uses the former.)